# unable to create a database with same name after deleting previous one

Tags: mongodb

I had a `database` named `questions`. I `dropped` it using `MongoDB Compass`. I am now trying to create it again using `mongosh` but I am getting the following error. Why?

```
test> show dbs
admin    40.00 KiB
config  108.00 KiB
local    80.00 KiB
test> use questions
switched to db questions
questions> db.createCollection("areas")
MongoServerError: db already exists with different case already have: [Questions] trying to create [questions]
questions> db.getCollectionNames();
[]
questions> db.getCollectionNames()
```

Comment: Is this a sharded cluster? What version?

Comment: laptop - `windows`. `$ mongosh --version` is `1.10.1`

Comment: You're running the `mongod` process (database) locally on your laptop? What version of the database?

Comment: yes, on my laptop. version is `6.0.8`